# How to calculate O(n) for two variables that increases differently in loop?

Tags: algorithm, input, data-structures, execution-time

I tried many way and i created n,i,t value table.I noticed that n=1 loop 0 time returns,n=2 loop=1 time ,n=3 or 4 loop=2 time, n=5,6 or 7 loop=3 ,n=8,9,10,11 loop=4 four time i found these values full-comprehend but i does not find solution O(n) for this algorithm.

```
function func3(n)
i = 1;
t = 1;
while i < n do
i = i + t;
t = t + 1;
end while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statemnts in loop repeat until `i < n`.
What is `i`? `i` is sum of natural numbers `i=1+2+3+...x`. Formula for sum of first `x` natural numbers is `S=(x(x+1))/2`.
Your expression in loop is `i < n`. This meen that `(x(x+1))/2 < n`. When we solve the inequality, we obtain `x<(-1+sqrt(1+8n))/2`. Since the number of loop iteration in integer, number of iterations is firts int lower then max `x`.
For example:

```
n = 1, x<0,823 => number of iterations is 0
n = 2, x<1,436 => number of iterations is 1
n = 11, x<4,164 => number of iterations is 4
```